¿Cómo puedo hacer para que Flutter v3.16.9 trabaje con Dart v2.19.6?
Estoy intentando ejecutar un proyecto compartido en VSCode en el cual se ha trabajado con las versiones de Flutter v3.16.9 y Dart v2.19.6, el problema es que a pesar de haber configurado las variables de entorno (cambiándolas de una a otra posición), haber indicado el path de las carpeta de los SDKs en VSCode, me indica que desde Flutter usa v3.16.9 y Dart v2.19.6 (que es ,o que quiero) pero al ejecutar flutter doctor -v dice que está utilizando la versión de Dart 3.2.6  y pues al momento de ejecutar el proyecto me arroja un error de librerías (por la incompatibilidad de mi versión actual con la que está configurada el proyecto)



¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar el problema de que mi Flutter lea la v2.19.6 y no la v3.2.6? Muchas gracias.

No recuerdo muy bien, pero ¿no que la carpeta de Flutter de por sí ya contiene el SDK de Dart? Igual, considero que hagas caso al mensaje de solución: consider adding  to the front of your path. Y por si no se entendió: ¿intentaste cambiar el orden de esas rutas en el PATH? ¿Intentaste eliminar la ruta de dart-sdk en el PATH?
